# How can I print true b&w with Epson Discproducer PP-100? (no CYM color ink used)

Tags: grayscale

I would like to print a true b&w image on discs using the Epson Discproducer PP-100 but when I select Black in the Discproducer print settings it still uses a bit of color ink (CYM). I was told by Epson it was because the image I made in Photoshop (CS3) grayscale still has color info in it but I was able to save a K only image and still prints a bit of color with he PP-100 (visible in light areas of the image especially). Has anyone had this problem & found a solution? I would be extremely grateful for a solution (if there is one) thanks.

Comment: Did you try the gray scale option

Comment: there is no grayscale option and the Black option prints all CYMK inks unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Printer drivers sometimes add other paints to make rich black. I usually test them by sending bitmap file or print plates from Acrobat.
**IF**
the printer driver still split the file into CMYK I use empty ink cartridges and force printing in black only.

Comment: Thanks but Bitmap not possible since it needs to be a standard full tone b&W photo.

Comment: Bitmap is just to see how the printer drivers act. You can't have "color information" in bitmap so it would need to be added by epson drivers. If the bitmap will print properly then you know that work is to do in photoshop or use different program to get rid of that color info

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, unfortunately. As stated in the PP-100N User's Guide section notes, *Maintenance: Changing the ink cartridge*, on page 125:

> Even when Black is selected in the printer driver, all the ink colors
>   are used in an operation designed to maintain the printing and print
>   head quality.

Answer (score 0):

Epson and many other office printers need RGB input. This makes sense because ordinary office software have no idea about CMYK.

If you have Adobe InDesign, try to print something with selecting the output to your printer to be CMYK. That option is not available at all, if your printer wants the data as RGB.

Adobe Acrobat (not Adobe Reader)has plenty of options in the tab "print production" It does not discuss about CMYK separations if the target printer is RGB input only.

RGB input printer has its own way to output the color R=G=B=0. Unfortunately the printer driver usually has no selectable options to define "let R+G=B=0 to be printed as 100% K.

**About the brute force solution**: Empty CMY cartridges can leave air into your system that can later be fatal for non-black printing. Additionally it does not make 100% K. But you can try to make a custom bottle collection that has CMYK bottles with their appropriate identification chips, but only black ink in all bottles. Surely it takes some time to clean the pipes for color printing.